# Where to put domain objects in my application

Tags: django, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, anemic-domain-model

So in my python django application the architecture is structured such that it is separated into different apps. One app for `users`, one for `finance`, etc.

Each app has the following base structure:

```
app_name
    models
    services
    tests
```

I am developing a new feature to support promo codes. Promo codes will allow the user to receive a discount for their upcoming bill(s). So I created a `PromoCodeModel` and a `PromoCodeService`. Inside the service I need to check if a user is eligible to redeem this code. It seems like this logic could get fairly complicated and I was hoping to encapsulate the eligibility checks into its own class -- something like `PromoCodeEligibility(user, promo_code)`.

I was wondering -- where would this belong? Should I create a new `PromoCodeEligibilityService`? Or should I create a new folder called `domain` and make this a domain object? I could also move this logic into the `model` itself but having really fat models seems like more of an anti-pattern to me. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm digging into the same questions. Have you found something from 2015 til now?

Answer (score 0):

> I could also move this logic into the model itself but having really
>   fat models seems like more of an anti-pattern to me. Thoughts?

Actually this is the preferred way in Django. You can read more about this [here](http://redbeacon.github.io/2014/01/28/Fat-Models-a-Django-Code-Organization-Strategy/) and [here](http://www.dabapps.com/blog/django-models-and-encapsulation/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590468/django-fat-models-and-skinny-controllers).

*PS. I'm pretty sure there were a few sentences about the topic inside django docs, but can't find it.*

Comment: Let us assume we aren't using django though -- where would it go then?

Comment: Also those article are simply advocating not to put the logic in the views, etc. I am basically trying to split up "fat models" into separate classes. meaning it will still live at the domain layer.